# How do I deal with square, cubic, etc. zeros and poles when manually drawing a Bode Plot?

Tags: frequency, analysis

I'm manually drawing a straight-line Bode magnitude plot. Say, I have the following transfer function in standard form for a Bode plot:

$$
T(j\omega) = \frac{1+j\omega/10}{(1+j\omega/50)^2}
$$

Should I treat the pole at \$\omega_C = 50\$ rad/s as I would treat the zero at \$\omega_C = 10\$ (except that it would have opposite slope change), or is there something special I have to do with repeated corner frequencies?

### References

1. *The Analysis and Design of Linear Circuits*, Thomas
2. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bode_plot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The slope change is 20dB/decade multiplied by the order (squared, cubed, etc.) of the pole or zero. The pole at \$\omega_C = 50 rad/s\$ would change the slope by -40dB/decade. The same applies for the phase: the mentioned pole would shift it by -90deg/decade (\$2\times-45deg/dec\$), starting one decade earlier.